# SWT GC fill colors for top half and bottom half of circle

Tags: java, swt

I'm looking to draw a circle with a line separating top half and bottom half of the circle, then fill colors for top half and bottom half using GC.

I'm able to do that if the line crosses the center of the circle like this (To rotate the line, I can simply change the startAngle of the fillArc()):

[image]

But if the line moves up or down vertically and/or is rotated, I'm having trouble filling the top half and bottom half like this:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fill top half and bottom half if the line moves up or down and/or is rotated?

Here is my code for the first image:

```
// Fill top half with red color
gc.setBackground( event.display.getSystemColor( SWT.COLOR_RED ) );
gc.fillArc( xCoord - ( diameter / 2 ),
            yCoord - ( diameter / 2 ),
            diameter,
            diameter,
            0,
            180 );

// Fill bottom half with blue color
gc.setBackground( event.display.getSystemColor( SWT.COLOR_BLUE ) );
gc.fillArc( xCoord - ( diameter/ 2 ),
            yCoord - ( diameter/ 2 ),
            diameter,
            diameter,
            180,
            180 );

// Draw the line separating top half and bottom half
Transform transform = new Transform( event.display );
transform.translate( xCoord, yCoord );
transform .rotate( 0);
gc.setTransform( transform );
gc.drawLine( -diameter / 2, 0, diameter / 2, 0 );
transform.dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible way is to:

1. draw the full blue circle with no clipping
2. draw the full red circle clipped by a calculated (and possibly rotated) rectangle which will overwrite part of the blue circle
3. draw the circle outline
4. draw the separation line using the appropriate segment of the previous clipping rectangle and clipped by the circle outline

I've created a class that implements this solution and a small program to test it.

For point 2, I've found the use of `Tranform` to perform the rotation to be very problematic since it will transform the whole display, and I wasn't able to find a way to limit the transformations to a limited area.
Instead I've used [Eclipse GEF](https://www.eclipse.org/gef/) to create a [Rectangle](https://github.com/eclipse/gef/wiki/Geometry#rectangle), rotate it and transform it to `PathData` which can be used to clip.

For point 4, I've reused the `PathData` from point 2 to draw the bottom segment of the clipping rectangle which is equivalent to the separation line between the 2 colors.
To avoid drawing part of the segment outside the circle I've clipped it with the circle outline.

This is the result:

[image: SeparatedCircleTest]

This is the test program, use the arrow keys to move/rotate the separation line:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

import static org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyListener.keyPressedAdapter;

public class SeparatedCircleTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setSize(600, 600);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        // double buffering to avoid flickering while redrawing the circle
        final SeparatedCircle separatedCircle = new SeparatedCircle(shell, SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED, 300, 300, 200, 0, 0.f);

        // to move/rotate the separation
        separatedCircle.addKeyListener(keyPressedAdapter(e -> {
            if(e.keyCode == SWT.ARROW_UP) {
                separatedCircle.setySeparationDelta(separatedCircle.getySeparationDelta() - 5);
            } else if(e.keyCode == SWT.ARROW_DOWN) {
                separatedCircle.setySeparationDelta(separatedCircle.getySeparationDelta() + 5);
            } else if(e.keyCode == SWT.ARROW_LEFT) {
                separatedCircle.setSeparationAngle(separatedCircle.getSeparationAngle() + 5.f);
            } else if(e.keyCode == SWT.ARROW_RIGHT) {
                separatedCircle.setSeparationAngle(separatedCircle.getSeparationAngle() - 5.f);
            }

            if(separatedCircle.needRedraw()) {
                separatedCircle.redraw();
            }
        }));

        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

And this is the implementation class:

```
import org.eclipse.gef.geometry.convert.swt.Geometry2SWT;
import org.eclipse.gef.geometry.euclidean.Angle;
import org.eclipse.gef.geometry.planar.Polygon;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Path;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.PathData;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;

public class SeparatedCircle extends Canvas {

    private int xCoord;
    private int yCoord;
    private int diameter;
    private int ySeparationDelta;
    private float separationAngle;

    private boolean needRedraw;
    private Rectangle circleBounds;
    private PathData clippingData;

    public SeparatedCircle(Composite parent, int style, int x, int y, int diameter, int ySeparationDelta, float separationAngle) {
        super(parent, style);

        xCoord = x;
        yCoord = y;
        this.diameter = diameter;
        this.ySeparationDelta = ySeparationDelta;
        this.separationAngle = separationAngle;

        needRedraw = true;

        addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
            public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
                paint(e);
            }
        });
    }

    private void paint(PaintEvent event) {

        // if some variable changed, we recalculate the bounds
        if(needRedraw) {
            calculateBounds();
            needRedraw = false;
        }

        GC gc = event.gc;

        // enable high quality drawing
        gc.setAntialias(SWT.ON);
        gc.setInterpolation(SWT.HIGH);

        // draw the first circle, no clipping
        gc.setBackground( event.display.getSystemColor( SWT.COLOR_BLUE ) );
        gc.fillOval(circleBounds.x, circleBounds.y, circleBounds.width, circleBounds.height);

        // clipping for the second circle
        Path clipping = new Path(gc.getDevice(), clippingData);
        gc.setClipping(clipping);
        clipping.dispose();

        // draw the second circle
        gc.setBackground( event.display.getSystemColor( SWT.COLOR_RED ) );
        gc.fillOval(circleBounds.x, circleBounds.y, circleBounds.width, circleBounds.height);

        // remove the clipping
        gc.setClipping((Rectangle) null);

        // draw the circle outline
        gc.setForeground(event.display.getSystemColor( SWT.COLOR_BLACK ));
        gc.setLineWidth(4);
        gc.drawOval(circleBounds.x, circleBounds.y, circleBounds.width, circleBounds.height);

        // clipping for the separation line
        Path circlePath = new Path(gc.getDevice());
        circlePath.addArc(circleBounds.x, circleBounds.y, circleBounds.width, circleBounds.height, 0.f, 360.f);
        gc.setClipping(circlePath);
        circlePath.dispose();

        // draw the separation line
        // we want to draw the bottom segment of the clipping rectangle (the third segment), so we use its third and fourth point
        gc.drawLine(
                (int) clippingData.points[4], // third point x
                (int) clippingData.points[5], // third point y
                (int) clippingData.points[6], // fourth point x
                (int) clippingData.points[7]  // fourth point y
        );
    }

    private void calculateBounds() {
        circleBounds = calculateCircleBounds();
        clippingData = calculateClipping();
    }

    private Rectangle calculateCircleBounds() {
        return new Rectangle(calculateLeft(), calculateTop(), diameter, diameter);
    }

    private int calculateLeft() {
        return xCoord - ( diameter / 2 );
    }

    private int calculateTop() {
        return yCoord - ( diameter / 2 );
    }

    private PathData calculateClipping() {

        // create the clipping rectangle
        org.eclipse.gef.geometry.planar.Rectangle rectangle = new org.eclipse.gef.geometry.planar.Rectangle(
                circleBounds.x, circleBounds.y, circleBounds.width, calculateClippingRectangleHeight());

        // rotate it, using the center of our circle as its point of rotation
        Polygon rotatedRectangle = rectangle.getRotatedCCW(Angle.fromDeg(separationAngle), xCoord, yCoord);

        // convert the rotated rectangle to PathData
        return Geometry2SWT.toSWTPathData(rotatedRectangle.toPath());
    }

    private int calculateClippingRectangleHeight() {
        return circleBounds.height / 2 + ySeparationDelta;
    }

    public int getxCoord() {
        return xCoord;
    }

    public void setxCoord(int xCoord) {
        this.xCoord = xCoord;
        needRedraw = true;
    }

    public int getyCoord() {
        return yCoord;
    }

    public void setyCoord(int yCoord) {
        this.yCoord = yCoord;
        needRedraw = true;
    }

    public int getDiameter() {
        return diameter;
    }

    public void setDiameter(int diameter) {
        this.diameter = diameter;
        needRedraw = true;
    }

    public int getySeparationDelta() {
        return ySeparationDelta;
    }

    public void setySeparationDelta(int ySeparationDelta) {
        this.ySeparationDelta = ySeparationDelta;
        needRedraw = true;
    }

    public float getSeparationAngle() {
        return separationAngle;
    }

    public void setSeparationAngle(float separationAngle) {
        this.separationAngle = separationAngle;
        needRedraw = true;
    }

    public boolean needRedraw() {
        return needRedraw;
    }

}
```

**To use GEF:**

To use GEF you should just need to include the following jars:

```
org.eclipse.gef.geometry.convert.swt.Geometry2SWT<version>.jar
org.eclipse.gef.geometry<version>.jar
```

You can retrieve them in the "plugin" folder from the builds here: https://www.eclipse.org/gef/downloads/index.php.

Choose the latest version and click on the update site link to download the full zip.